# Having trouble getting the total number of cancelled bookings in R

Tags: r, summarize

I tried pulling the total number of canceled bookings from a data frame: bookings_df

This is the syntax I wrote in R:

number_of_canceled_bookings<-bookings_df%% summarize(is_canceled)

Whenever I run this syntax, it has an error of **Error: object 'is_canceled' not found**

the data frame that I am trying to access is bookings_df and the column that I want to have a sum total of is is_canceled

Upon further checking the bookings_df data frame, I saw that the values under the column is_canceled are integers.

What can I do to solve this issue?

I tried running this syntax number_of_canceled_bookings<-bookings_df%% summarize(is_canceled) expecting it to pull the total number of cancelled bookings.

Comment: Looks like a syntax issue; perhaps try `number_of_canceled_bookings <- bookings_df %>% summarize(cancelled_bookings = sum(is_canceled, na.rm = TRUE))`